# Hostapd is very slow (at 5Mbps)

Tags: 13.04, wireless, hostapd

I've set up hostapd wifi hotspot but it is working on very low speed. What may be possible cause for this? Windows client shows it is 802.11n but link speed is 5Mbps (and real speed is less than 2Mbps)

```
root@home:~# uname -r
3.8.0-30-generic

root@home:~# lspci -v
02:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
        Subsystem: AzureWave AW-NB037H 802.11bgn Wireless Half-size Mini PCIe Card [AR9002WB-1NGCD]
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28
        Memory at fe9f0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
        Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Capabilities: [60] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
        Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
        Capabilities: [170] Power Budgeting <?>
        Kernel driver in use: ath9k

root@home:~# lsmod | grep ath
ath9k                 149924  0
ath9k_common           14055  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              413629  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
ath                    23827  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
mac80211              606457  1 ath9k
cfg80211              510937  3 ath,ath9k,mac80211

root@home:~# iwconfig
mon.wlan0  IEEE 802.11bgn  Mode:Monitor  Tx-Power=16 dBm
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  Mode:Master  Tx-Power=16 dBm
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

root@home:~# cat /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf | egrep -v "^(#.*)?$"
interface=wlan0
logger_syslog=-1
logger_syslog_level=2
logger_stdout=-1
logger_stdout_level=2
dump_file=/tmp/hostapd.dump
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd
ctrl_interface_group=0
ssid=poma
hw_mode=g
channel=1
beacon_int=100
dtim_period=2
max_num_sta=255
rts_threshold=2347
fragm_threshold=2346
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=3
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wmm_enabled=1
wmm_ac_bk_cwmin=4
wmm_ac_bk_cwmax=10
wmm_ac_bk_aifs=7
wmm_ac_bk_txop_limit=0
wmm_ac_bk_acm=0
wmm_ac_be_aifs=3
wmm_ac_be_cwmin=4
wmm_ac_be_cwmax=10
wmm_ac_be_txop_limit=0
wmm_ac_be_acm=0
wmm_ac_vi_aifs=2
wmm_ac_vi_cwmin=3
wmm_ac_vi_cwmax=4
wmm_ac_vi_txop_limit=94
wmm_ac_vi_acm=0
wmm_ac_vo_aifs=2
wmm_ac_vo_cwmin=2
wmm_ac_vo_cwmax=3
wmm_ac_vo_txop_limit=47
wmm_ac_vo_acm=0
ieee80211n=1
eapol_key_index_workaround=0
eap_server=0
own_ip_addr=127.0.0.1
wpa=3
wpa_passphrase=***
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK WPA-EAP
wpa_pairwise=TKIP CCMP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP

root@home:~# cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail
2223
```

Comment: Look [here](http://elinux.org/RPI-Wireless-Hotspot) *(I know it is for a Raspberry Pi, still works...)* - It may be to do with the `channel` or `driver`.

Comment: I have very slow interaction with a local freeradius server as well.